# C# WPF DataTable into a CollectionViewSource use that for a ViewList

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, collectionviewsource

I'm have gotten data from a database, now I want to put into a CollectionViewSource and then use that as the source for a ListView. I want to do this so I can filter the ListView. However I don't understand how pass the Datatable from c# to the XAML CollectionViewSource?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="NamesOfCompany"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="listView" ...
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource NamesOfCompany}}" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="CompanyName" 
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CompanyName}" />
        </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>

<Grid Margin="2,441.5,-2,0" Grid.Row="1" >
   <TextBox x:Name="txt_search" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TextSearch,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="234" Margin="0,0,451,8" TextChanged="txt_search_TextChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

All my data from my database is held in

```
private DataTable dt;
```

I'm not sure how you assign all the data from dt into the CollectionViewSource.

Comment: The CollectionViewSource has a Source property that you can DataBind or set from code behind.

Comment: But  DataTable and CollectionViewSource  are old, consider using EF an MVVM.

Comment: I heard of MVVM how does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a collectionviewsource to bind to datatable.  Simply connect the datatable directly to the ItemsSource.  One way to do this is in the code behind...

```
DataView dv = new DataView();
dv.Table = dt;
dv.Filter = "CompanyName='abc'";
listView.ItemsSource = dv;
```

Comment: Yes i was using that but i want to be able to filter it

Comment: Ok.  Many ways to do this also.  I've edited my answer.,

Comment: would this filter work in term of like a search box which when you typed in would change what its shows?

Comment: Yes, of course.  I'm not suggesting that you hardcode the filter to 'abc'.